Django PasswordResetForm Not Sending Emails to Users with Unusable Passwords
In my Django application, I am using the PasswordResetForm to allow users to reset their passwords. However, I noticed that users with unusable passwords do not receive password reset emails. The get_users method in PasswordResetForm filters out these users.
The Django documentation states:
The get_users method in the PasswordResetForm also filters out users with an unusable password, so those users don’t get emails either. You’ll have to either assign some type of password to those users or override that method in the form to not filter out by that condition.
Additionally, I receive a "200 OK" response and see the log entry GET /password-reset/done/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6626, but the emails are not being sent.
How can I resolve this issue?
Specifically, how can I either:
Assign a usable password to users who have an unusable password.
Override the get_users method in PasswordResetForm to include users with unusable passwords.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I have found the solution by overriding the get_users method:
class PasswordResetForm(auth_forms.PasswordResetForm):
    def get_users(self, email):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        email_field_name = UserModel.get_email_field_name()
        active_users = UserModel._default_manager.filter(
            **{f'{email_field_name}__iexact': email, 'is_active':True}
        )
        return (u for u in active_users)

